# Sending Images in an HTML mailto using PHP

Tags: php, html, image

Trying to send an image included with my mailto function within a share feature in my website. However when I'm trying to add the image within the mailto, it appears on the websites page with a link and nothing appears in the email.

[image]

I've tried this:
[image]-adding with a php echo
and adding an  in the body, but im sure im just doing it wrong

I will deal with which image sends on my end by instantiating an id, just need the logic for it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: note i removed the img for this picture, the img src below is properly working and supposed to be there.

Comment: Because you send plain tex, not some HTML. Also mail clients usually removes/restricts external sources as it's potential security issue . Use PHPMailer to properly attach images

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to encode an image into a `mailto:` scheme URL.

Comment: There is a duplicate for this.